# android:background not working with Theme.MaterialComponents

Tags: java, android, kotlin, material-design

Description: after I change my app them to `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar` , In my xml file Button label's `android:background="@drawable/login_btn_bg"` not working,and I can't set others color、shape or selector,they are not work.

Expected behavior: Button label's android:background= can normal work , when I set my app them to `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar` or others Material thems

Comment: use this app:backgroundTint="@null"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For solving problem you should insert this implementation in your ***build.gradle*** file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha06'
```